# CSS sidebar vanishes on resize in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, sidebar, window-resize

I want to highlight a sidebar with a background image. The background should strech from the top to the bottom of the window.

When the browser window is resized and the sidebar gets wider/narrower, the background should adapt to that size.

Here's a sample:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').css({
                "background": "url('images/sidebar_bg.png') repeat-y",
                "background-size": $('#sidebar').outerWidth() + "px"
            });

            $(window).resize(function() {
                $('body').css({
                    "background-size" : $('#sidebar').outerWidth() + "px"
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #sidebar {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
        #content {
            width: 80%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">Sidebar content</div>
        <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is working fine in both Firefox and IE, however in Chrome the sidebar vanishes on resize.

Comment: Working as you expected here http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/LtYyE/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need any jquery for that. Just use background css for the sidebar itself. Like this:

```
#sidebar {
 width:20%;
 float:left;
 background: url(images/sidebar.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

and this will spread out your image within sidebar

Comment: Thanks, but this will spread the background image only within the sidebar. I need it from the top to the bottom of the window.

Comment: then you should assign these css rules to body, but controll them via js like in your example, but with the change:

    "background-size" : $('#sidebar').outerWidth() + "px 100%"

It works for me, in Chrome also.

Comment: The second background-size argument made the difference. Thanks!